# How to load bitmap in touchimageview through Glide SDK 4.3.1?

Tags: android, android-glide

Am trying to load a file as bitmap into TouchImageview. If I use normal image view instead of Touch image view Glide library is able to load image into it from file object but in case on touch image view Glide unable to load image.

Used following code as well:

```
 Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load(file).into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(250, 250) {

            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                    touchImageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadFailed(@Nullable Drawable errorDrawable) {
                super.onLoadFailed(errorDrawable);
            }
        });
```

But **`OnLoadFailed()`** is called with errorDrawable as `null`.

Comment: Hello, have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I just found about xml. please take note that, you HAVE TO USE RELATIVE LAYOUT!

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <my.zuhrain.kit.TouchImageView
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/image_view_main"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="400dp" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

and here we go

```
 storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                //things need to know
                //USE RELATIVE LAYOUT!
                Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .asBitmap()
                        .load(uri)
                        .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                                touchImageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
                            }
                        });
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: what is storageReference?

Comment: @reza_khalafi storageReference is from Firebase. I got the url from Firebase. It was my case